# Unresolved package/class/symbol Android.manifest flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest, audio-service

I downloaded a project from github and able to run it but I'm having these errors in manifest file. Can anyone please guide how to resolve these errors? I've tried importing reuired dependencies and running pub get but unable to solve these. App is running but there's no audio in it.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.learn_quran_app">
    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <application
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:label="Learn Quran"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioServiceActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">



            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioService" android:exported="true">
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
          </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <receiver android:name="com.ryanheise.audioservice.MediaButtonReceiver" android:exported="true">
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
          </intent-filter>
        </receiver> 
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />


    </application>
</manifest>
```

[image]

Comment: First thing open the android part as stand alone project in android studio , then try to indexing the project and it will identify the problem for you